# Configuring SSH over USB on ARM AM335x running angstrom linux 3.2.0

Tags: ssh, usb, arm, embedded-linux

I have a AM335X ARM processor on a custom board. I am running angstrom linux 3.2.0 on it.

My build environment is a 64 bit laptop running Ubuntu 12.0.4.

I was hoping (I am a newbie), someone could explain what I need to do to configure the board (and host desktop) to run SSH over USB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate on which aspect of this question is related to programming? It sounds like a question for http://superuser.com/ to me - not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you have OTG port or not. If yes, you should configure it to emulate a network device. Connect your board to your laptop and you should see a new networking device (`usb0` or something like this). Configure IP addresses for both host `usb0` and one on your board and you're done having an extra IP subnet, where you can ping, SSH etc.